# Prevent section headers of UITableView from doing weird stuff when scrolled past content bounds?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Let me elaborate on "weird stuff." My app has a table view with stuff in it, as most table views do. There's also a translucent black bar along the top of the screen through which table view content is visible as it scrolls past, à la the iPhone photos app.

All of this works fine, except when the section header view scrolls past the top bar, it gets pushed up and the next section header takes its place floating at the top. The previous section header ends up pushed upwards, leaving a small gap where it should be. I imagine this is what happens all the time, but it's only visible now because I'm showing part of the table view past the content area.

I realize this is very difficult to explain with words, so here are pictures:

[image]

Everything looks good so far...

[image]

..when suddenly, a huge white gap behind the nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tableview bounds to not be hidden under the translucent bar like:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height-44);
```

or you can make the bar non-transparent, I suppose.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but I guess there is no answer outside of "Apple never intended for translucent bars to be used with section headers." :/